# jquery ajax in wordpress metabox

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, meta-boxes

i build a word press page builder meta box,
my meta box work properly, but i think that is mistake, or i have better ways to do that better, my problem is append() jquery function. that is very complicated and Sapagty code. and i know i should't php codes in jquery append(), i want to do that with jquery Ajax. but i don't know what i should to do, can you show me a true or better way!

```
$page_builder = array(
array(
    'id'      => 'module',
    'type'    => 'tab',
    'title'   => __( 'tab', 'tx' ),
    'fields'  => array(
        array(
            'id'      => 'module_title',
            'type'    => 'text',
            'title'   => __( 'Module Title', 'tx' ),
        ),
        array(
            'id'      => 'module_numbers',
            'type'    => 'text',
            'title'   => __( 'Max Number of Post', 'tx' ),
        ),
        array(
            'id'      => 'module_offset',
            'type'    => 'text',
            'title'   => __( 'Posts Offset', 'tx' ),
        ),
        array(
            'id'      => 'module_category',
            'type'    => 'category',
            'title'   => __( 'Filter by Category', 'tx' ),
        ),
    ),
),
);

function call_metabox() {

global $page_builder;

$terms = get_terms( 'category', 'get=all' );

?>

<script>
    jQuery(document).ready( function() {

        var count    = 1;
        var button   = jQuery('.add-module');
        var panels   = jQuery('.panels');
        var geturi   = '<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>';
        var category = '<?php foreach ( $terms as $term ){ echo '<option value="'. $term->slug .'">'. $term->name .'</option>'; } ?>';

        button.live( 'click', function() {

            panels.append(
            '<li>'+
            '<div><?php _e( 'sample', 'tx' ); ?></div>'+
            '<div>'+geturi+'/img.png'+'</div>'+
            '<div><select name="<?php echo $page_builder[0]['fields'][0]['id']; ?>" id="">'+category+'</select></div>'+
            '<div>'+'<input type="text" name="module_title['+ count +'][title]" id="module_title['+ count +'][title]" value="" />'+'</div>'+
            '</li>'
            );

            count++;

        });

    });
</script>


<input type="button" id="add-module" class="add-module" value="<?php _e( 'Add New Module', 'tx' ) ?>">

<ul class="panels">

</ul>

< ?php
}
```

thank you.

Comment: there is a legendary function in php called `echo`

Answer (score 0):

you can put the js code in a .js file and then insert the script with wp_enqueue_script:

```php
//this will register the script
wp_register_script(
    'my_script_id',
    plugins_url( '/assets/js/scritp.js', PLUGIN_URL ), 
    [ 'JQuery' ], // define dependencies
    null, 
    true 
);

// this will pass data from php to js script
// it will output 'var object = { attribute: 'value' }' before script insertion 
wp_localize_script( 
    'my_script_id', 
    'object', 
    [
        'attribute'                       =>  'value'
    ]
);

// this will enqueue the script insertion
wp_enqueue_script( 'my_script_id' );


// this will insert the script
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_script_id' );
```